# Oracle migrate data from one database to another

Tags: oracle

How to copy data from one data base to another database table using script like procedure, cursor etc.
I am using oracle-sql developer.

Answer (score 1):

Doing it using a script *like procedure, cursor etc.* is not the way to do it. Oracle offers [Data Pump](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil/oracle-data-pump-overview.html) export and import utilities which are designed to *move* data around, so I'd suggest you to use them.

Comment: The schema is different for tables in the new db,. Also i want to copy only say top 100 records from a table to the new table. Is this posiible with data pump

Comment: If tables' description is different, then it won't work. You can include a WHERE clause while exporting data, but - that can't help for the 1st reason (different columns in tables). So - it seems that you'll have to write your own migration procedures, after all. I don't know whether there's any *shortcut* available in tool you use (SQL Developer), sorry.